# Second last value (pandas, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, min

I have the following dataframe:

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 3 |
| 1 | a | 4 |
| 2 | b | 9 |
| 3 | b | 6 |
| 4 | a | 2 |
| 5 | b | 1 |

And I would like to get the second last value of each group of column "A".
I already figured out how to get the min() value with a groupby :

```
df_grouped_last = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': ['min']})
```

But I need to get the second last value ("before last") so I can get :

| index | A | 2nd last B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 3 |
| 1 | b | 6 |

I will also need the third last and fourth in another work.

Any chance someone know how to code it ?

Thanks a lot !
Vincent

Comment: I think second last value for `a` will be `4` not `3`.

Comment: @VincJ I think you should mention that each group is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your expected output, the assumption is that column `B` is sorted for each group. If that is the case, use [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), combined with [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
(df.sort_values(['A', 'B'])
   .groupby('A', sort = False)
   .B
   .nth(-2) # familiar python construct ... 
            # takes second value from the bottom, per group
   .reset_index()
 )

   A  B
0  a  3
1  b  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `sort_values` then use position

```
out = df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1])
Out[68]: 
   index  A  B
A             
a      0  a  3
b      3  b  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have an error : IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.
I think it's because the second last value may exist for some individual group of column A, or a group will be define only by one value. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: @VncJ `df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[[1]] if len(x)>1 else x)`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = (df.groupby('A', as_index = False)['B']
        .agg({'2nd last B': lambda x: x.iloc[-2] if len(x) > 1 else x}))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  2nd last B
0  a           4
1  b           6
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have an error with this code too : IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds (see above).

Comment: @VncJ I guess there are cases where a group doesn't contain enough rows i.e. number of rows in a group < 2.